# Solidity: get bit at position in bytes32

Tags: binary, byte, ethereum, solidity, evm

I need to read each of the 256 bits stored in a bytes32 variable. I'm using Solidity 8.1

Thank you for any help you can offer

Answer (score 0):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Test {
  // 1 byte is enough to hold about 1 typed character, 4 x "abcdefgh"
  bytes32 public test = "abcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefgh";
 
  function accessByteByIndex(uint index) public view returns(bytes1) {
    // since you need 32 bytes
    require(index<32,"Index out of range");
    return test[index];
  }
 
  function reverseBytes() public pure returns(bytes memory) {
    uint num = 32;
    bytes memory chars = new bytes(num);
    bytes memory reverse = new bytes(num);
 
    chars = "abcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefgh";
 
    uint i = 0;
 
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      reverse[i] = chars[num - 1 - i];
    }
 
    return reverse;
  }
 
}
```

Comment: I was asking about accessing the individual bits not the bytes. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

needed to cast the bytes32 variable to a uint256 then use the following function:

```
function isBitSet(uint256 b, uint256 pos) public pure returns (bool) {
        return ((b >> pos) & 1) == 1;
    }
```